# Regex match greater than or less than symbol followed by any numbers

Tags: regex

I want to match on `>21` or `>2` or `>0` or `<12` or `<45` , you get the idea.

I tried `myString.match(/^><:\d+$/)` but it is wrong. What should i use for this case?

Comment: Regex in which language? Java, Python, JavaScript??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
^[><]\d+$
```

Either of the symbols inside the square brackets `[]` are acceptable. Followed by any number of digits (at least `1`).

This will match all such patterns: `>21` or `>2` or `>0` or `<12` or `<45`.

And so your code becomes:

```
myString.match(/^[><]\d+$/)
```

You can refer to some of the basics [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)